# How to find common ancestor for two branches programmatically

Tags: git, go, go-git

I am working on a project where I integrated my project with `git`. For integration purpose, I am using `go-git` library. My question is how can I find a common ancestor for two branches programmatically? I want to implement this function. Looks like `go-git`and other go library do not provide such functionality.

Comment: https://github.com/src-d/go-git/issues/679

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is small program using `go-git` that mimics the behavior of `git merge-base --all`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4"
    . "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/_examples"
    "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing"
    "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/object"
    "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/storer"
)

// store h in set, s, handling nil s if necessary. Return new set.
func store(s map[plumbing.Hash]bool, h plumbing.Hash) map[plumbing.Hash]bool {
    if s == nil {
        s = make(map[plumbing.Hash]bool)
    }
    s[h] = true
    return s
}

// mergeBase finds best common ancestors between two commits to use in a
// three-way merge. One common ancestor is better than another common ancestor
// if the latter is an ancestor of the former. A common ancestor that does not
// have any better common ancestor is a best common ancestor, i.e. a merge base.
// Note that there can be more than one merge base for a pair of commits.
func mergeBase(s storer.EncodedObjectStorer, a, b plumbing.Hash) ([]plumbing.Hash, error) {
    commitA, err := object.GetCommit(s, a)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    commitB, err := object.GetCommit(s, b)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Mapping of direct descendants of each commit we visit
    desc := make(map[plumbing.Hash]map[plumbing.Hash]bool)

    // Set of commits reachable from a
    reachableFromA := make(map[plumbing.Hash]bool)

    // Walk commits reachable from A
    err = object.NewCommitPreorderIter(commitA, nil, nil).ForEach(func(c *object.Commit) error {
        reachableFromA[c.Hash] = true
        for _, h := range c.ParentHashes {
            desc[h] = store(desc[h], c.Hash)
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Set of common commits between a and b
    common := make(map[plumbing.Hash]bool)

    // Walk commits reachable from B
    err = object.NewCommitPreorderIter(commitB, nil, nil).ForEach(func(c *object.Commit) error {
        if reachableFromA[c.Hash] {
            common[c.Hash] = true
        }
        for _, h := range c.ParentHashes {
            desc[h] = store(desc[h], c.Hash)
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    best := make(map[plumbing.Hash]bool)

    // Trim down the set of common commits to only those that are best
    for h := range common {
        best[h] = true
        for child := range desc[h] {
            if common[child] {
                // there is a descendant to h that is common to both a and b. h is not in best.
                delete(best, h)
                break
            }
        }
    }

    var result []plumbing.Hash
    for h := range best {
        result = append(result, h)
    }
    return result, nil
}

// Open an existing repository in a specific folder.
func main() {
    CheckArgs("<path> <commitA> <commitB>")
    path := os.Args[1]
    a := plumbing.NewHash(os.Args[2])
    b := plumbing.NewHash(os.Args[3])

    r, err := git.PlainOpen(path)
    CheckIfError(err)

    bases, err := mergeBase(r.Storer, a, b)
    CheckIfError(err)

    for _, b := range bases {
        fmt.Println(b)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the result of the command:

```
 git merge-base branch1 branch2
```